# Set Wagtail BooleanField value to True, disabled

Tags: wagtail, wagtail-streamfield

My team and I are building a "page builder" using the StreamField capabilities in `Wagtail 2.5.1`. We've built a number of modules which will be used by our marketing team. One of the module requests is a "divider bar".

I've created it with some very simple code:

```
class DividerBlock(blocks.StructBlock):

    include_divider = blocks.BooleanBlock(
        required=False,
        help_text='Display a divider bar',
        default=True,
    )

    class Meta:
        label = 'Divider Module'
        icon = 'horizontalrule'
```

I don't actually *need* the checkbox because I'm simply looking for the existence of this module on the page, and we'll output the HR. But if I don't include at least one control, the streamfield shows an empty space, so a checkbox makes sense. However I want to force the checkbox to default to true (already done) AND be disabled or readonly so that the user cannot change it.

I've tried both disabled and readonly as properties in the BooleanBlock init but neither are working. Is there a way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 2):

For blocks that just need to occupy a place in the stream but not have any data of their own, Wagtail provides the block type [StaticBlock](https://docs.wagtail.io/en/stable/topics/streamfield.html#staticblock).

Comment: Aha! I knew there had to be some way to do this. Thanks @gasman!